# Condition of mucus coated trachea, but clear lungs?

Tags: terminology, breathing, mucus-phlegm, respiratory-system, trachea-windpipe

Is there a medical condition or illness (what's the terminology??) for when there is an acute incidence of when the trachea is coated with so much mucus and phlegm that it causes labored breathing and swallowing, but the airways in the lungs are completely clear? So when a person goes to the doctor, the doctor will hear the lungs as clear even though the patient is struggling to breathe because the trachea is clogged with mucus?

Comment: If the trachea or bronchial passages are full of enough mucus to cause labored breathing, a doctor will most certainly hear it. It will be loud and obvious. If they don't hear it, then it's probably not there and the problem is something else.